# Stock software for toys

Tags: inventory

I am looking for a stockkeeping/inventory management application that can easily follow up on incoming and outgoing goods. It does not have to make invoices or do bookkeeping. It would also be interesting if we could make mutiple adjustments because we are a little tired of constantly adjusting 3-4 different files in excel everytime an item is sold on our webshop.

Preferably a free application, if possible, or one with a trial period so we can decide.

Preferably either a Windows 7 desktop application or a web application.  The ability to check up on stock whilst being away from the computer is a BIG PLUS.

We currently do it combining Excel and Dropbox accessing our files via the mobile if we need something.

Is there an application out there?

Comment: Mobile (Android, iOS, ..)? Stationary (Linux, Mac, Windows)? Web-App? What features are needed? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) – and then [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: What's the issue with Excel?

Comment: The issue is being forced to adjust multiple files at the same time. Like sales, to register the sales, the stock file also has to be adjusted. Same with incoming goods (2 files to be adjusted).

I would like to see an automated procedure.